# Change status bar style with animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, statusbar, uistatusbar

Since `UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarStyle(.default, animated: true)` is deprecated from IOS9 is it possible to change status bar style with *animation* on `push`? I cannot find any description in docs.

Comment: UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent  Have you used this

Comment: This will not change the bar with animation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's now a variable you have to override:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle
override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation
```

Depending on when you update the status bar, you might also have to call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()`

Comment: It is not being called from UIViewController

Comment: Where are you trying to set the status bar style?

Comment: in viewWillAppear

Comment: Can you update your question with code so we can understand better?

Comment: The problem was that I previously set View controller-based status bar appearance to NO

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set status bar style, application level then set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `NO` in your `.plist` file.

if you wan to set status bar style, at view controller level then follow these steps:

1. Set the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `YES` in the `.plist` file, if you need to set status bar style at UIViewController level only.
2. In the viewDidLoad add function - `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate`
3. override preferredStatusBarStyle in your view controller.

-

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Set value of .plist according to status bar style setup level.
[image]

Comment: It is not being called from UIViewController

Answer (score 1):

To tackle the animation part the way I made it transition smoothly between `.lightContent` and `.default` was to use something similar to below each time you change it.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
```

Place that in your VC you want the status bar to animate and you'll have a nice smooth animation.

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return lightStatusBar ? .lightContent : .default
}
```

Above is a snippet of me changing the content based on a condition I have.